# Microsoft word Database quick part - How to use a mergefield as a filter for the database query

Tags: database, ms-word, custom-fields, mailmerge

I am using mail merge to input data from an excel sheet. Everthing works great and I can access my variables using «MyMergefield»

Now I need for each letter generated to look into another excel file and do a query that will take the «MyMergefield» as a query filter SELECT FROM x WHERE field1 = «MyMergefield»

The way I am proceeding is "inserting a quick part" => "Field" in my word document. 
In the quickpart dialog, I choose "DataBase", then I choose my excel file.

once the data source is chosen, There an option to change the request parameters, I click on it and I get the filter configuration popup where I can choose the field (from the excel sheet), the operator ("equals" in this case). Then there's the compare with field. In my case its not as simple as comparing to as string. Its comparing to a mail merge field.

I tried the following syntax:

«Myfield»

MERGEFIELD Myfield

MERGEFIELD "Myfield"

{MergeField Myfield}

{ MERGEFIELD Myfield}

None worked, it complained that it did not find any match so it did not insert the database (Of course it will not find any match to the syntax if I don't run mail merge)

I did look directly in the openxml file of an existing example (because I can't edit existing quickpart - Correct me if Im wrong) and the database query looked like:

```
FROM `Candidates$` WHERE ((`column` = '</w:instrText>
...
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD Myfield</w:instrText>
</w:r>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: It's usually much easier when working with fields, particularly Fields like DATABASE fields, to get used to working with the field code directly, using alt-F9 to reveal the codes, ctrl-F9 to insert new pairs of the special field braces {}, F9 to update the values of the fields in the Selection, and so on. With one exception, using the dialogs in the User Interface will not usually let you insert the nested field code that you need here.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a way to edit the source code directly. I just hit alt-F9 and finally all the code appears! Thanks again